# Adding multiple set of key-value pair of data in ASP.Net Core with Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I need to create a form that collects multiple key-value pairs of data from the user. I am using a dictionary to model this data. In my form, the user inserts a key and value and if needs to add more than one pair then a (+) icon is pressed for new fields to appear. In case the user decides to delete a key and value pair, a delete icon needs to be clicked to remove the key-value pair. I started coding the behavior of the form with jQuery and JavaScript as the backend is made in C#, but soon it started to get more complicated. I have tried to use Razor page and asp tag helpers, but they are not helpful in creating the sequence of events as I would like to. I am wondering how such a situation can be addressed most appropriately in ASP.Net Core 2.2

```
    <div id="otherProperty">
                    <i id="deleteProperty" class="material-icons">delete</i>
                    <input id="otherPropertyKey" name="propertyKey" type="text" placeholder="Property name"/>
                    <input id="otherPropertyValue" name="propertyValue" type="text" placeholder="Property value"/>
                    <i id="addProperty" class="material-icons">&#xe147;</i>
</div>
 <div>
       <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </div>
```

[image]

The model for the OtherProperties is:

```
public class OtherProperties:IOtherProperties
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _otherProperties;
        public OtherProperties()
        {
            _otherProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> GetOtherProperties()
        {
            return _otherProperties;
        }

        public void AddProperty(string key, string value)
        {
            if (!_otherProperties.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _otherProperties.Add(key,value);
            }
        }

        public void RemoveProperty(string key)
        {
            if (_otherProperties.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _otherProperties.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the interface is

```
 public interface IOtherProperties
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> GetOtherProperties();
        void AddProperty(string key, string value);
        void RemoveProperty(string key);
    }
```

Comment: pssst, this isn't a JS or jQuery question. this is a .net/mvc question

Comment: Use the index in the collection in razor page and make a model that have a public list of simple KeyValue object

Comment: Unfortunately this is too broad. End of day, ASP.Net, Core or any flavor, does **not** change HTTP requests/responses. That said, you can construct your payload on the client side using any flavor of JS/Library and `POST` it to a controller for processing - again, in any flavor: mapping/binding to a `model` or via _raw_ request params.

Comment: Please provide you controller code. And where is `OtherProperties` used?

Comment: @Alexander I have answered the question. I will provide a Blazor solution later as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this by using JavaScript. Without Blazor, you can't use pure ASP.Net Razor to achieve this. The JavaScript code that I wrote is as follows:

```
 <div id="otherProperties">
                <div id="otherProperty-0">
                    <i id="deleteProperty-0" class="material-icons" onclick="RemoveProperty(id)">delete</i>
                    <input id="otherPropertyKey-0" name="propertyKey-0" type="text" placeholder="Property name"/>
                    <input id="otherPropertyValue-0" name="propertyValue-0" type="text" placeholder="Property value"/>
                    <i id="addProperty" class="material-icons" onclick="AddProperty()">&#xe147;</i>
                </div>
```

Then JavaScript code would be like this

```
var idCounter = 1;
var keyValuePairArray = ['0']; 


function AddProperty() {
    if(document.getElementById('deleteProperty-'.concat(idCounter-1)) !== null) {
        document.getElementById('deleteProperty-'.concat(idCounter - 1)).style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    var newProperty = GenerateOtherProperty(idCounter);
    document.getElementById('otherProperties').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newProperty);
    keyValuePairArray.push(idCounter.toString());
    idCounter = idCounter +1 ;
}

function RemoveProperty(id) {
    //from id extract the number
    var propId = id.toString().split('-')[1];
    document.getElementById('otherProperty-'.concat(propId)).remove();
    var index = keyValuePairArray.indexOf(propId.toString(),0);
    if(index > -1){
        keyValuePairArray.splice(index,1);
    }
}

function KeyValuePair(key,value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;   
}


function GetKeyValueInputBoxes() {
    var otherProps = [];
   for (i =0; i < keyValuePairArray.length; i++){
       var key = GetElement('otherPropertyKey-'.concat(keyValuePairArray[i])).value;
       var value = GetElement('otherPropertyValue-'.concat(keyValuePairArray[i])).value;
       var kvp = new KeyValuePair(key,value);
       otherProps.push(kvp);
   }  
   return otherProps;
}


/**
 * @return {string}
 */
function GenerateOtherProperty (counter) {
     var rawOtherProperty = ' <div id="otherProperty">\n' +
         '                <i id="deleteProperty" class="material-icons" onclick="RemoveProperty(id)">delete</i>\n' +
         '                <input id="otherPropertyKey" name="propertyKey" type="text" placeholder="Property name"/>\n' +
         '                <input id="otherPropertyValue" name="propertyValue" type="text" placeholder="Property value"/>\n' +
         '                 <i id="addProperty" class="material-icons" onclick="AddProperty()">&#xe147;</i>\n' +
         '            </div>';
     var freshProp = new DOMParser().parseFromString(rawOtherProperty,"text/html");
     freshProp.getElementById("otherProperty").id = 'otherProperty-'.concat(counter);
    freshProp.getElementById("deleteProperty").id = 'deleteProperty-'.concat(counter);
    freshProp.getElementById("otherPropertyKey").id = 'otherPropertyKey-'.concat(counter);
    freshProp.getElementById("otherPropertyValue").id = 'otherPropertyValue-'.concat(counter);

     return freshProp.body.innerHTML;   
}
```

So, by using JS we control the behavior of the UI and collect the values in the fields. We will convert the data to a JSON object and POST it as the raw body of a request to our Web API controller in the back.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/event")]
        public IActionResult ProcessForm([FromBody] JObject jsonRawBody)
        {
            var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>(jsonRawBody.ToString());
           // process jsonData

        }
```

Where Event model is :

```
  public class Event
    {
        [JsonProperty("otherKVP")]
        public IList<KeyValuePair<string,string>> OtherProperties { get; set; }

}
```